# Require a specific minimal Java version for an Applet

Tags: java, applet

My clients have JRE 1.3.x and 1.5.x installed, and when I use the `<applet>` tag, 1.3.x is often loaded by default by the browser. How can I request the browser to use JRE 1.5.x in this case?

Note: JRE upgrade on customer side is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how it works for other browser. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/family-clsid-140615.html) is an article to where you can specify a `JRE` family version for a Java applet to run in Java Plug-in for *Internet Explorer*.

Reference doc : [JavaTM Plug-in and Applet Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_execution.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use [deployJava.js](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to deploy the applet.  For the version, specify it as:

```
var version = '1.5';
```